# Dialogflow CX - Is there a way to get a Webhook response and use it inside a generator?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I'm getting some parameters to use inside the conversation from webhook, and I wuold like to use this information inside a generator. Google documentation says that Generators can use parameters gathered from the customer, but I can't find anything about webhooks.

Thanks

$session.params.favorouritefruit  (webhook respose, let's assume it apple)

Generator prompt

Describe $session.params.bestoffer

Ideal output:

An apple is a round or slightly oval fruit with sweet or tart flesh. It is the pomaceous fruit of the apple tree, also known as Malus domestica....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How about adding a page that sets information via webhook before the page with the generator?